# What's the actual value of an if-statement executing a command?

Tags: linux, shell

I do not quite understand what the following if-statement actually does, in the sense of what the condition outputs could possibly be:

```
if linux-command-1 | linux-command-2 | linux-command-3 > /dev/null
```

I understand the execution as the following:

1. Linux Command 1 gets executed, it's output is PIPED into Linux-Command-2 as input.
2. Linux Command 2 gets executed with LC1's input, it's output is PIPED into Linux-Command-3.
3. Linux Command 3 gets executed with LC2's input, it's output is redirected into /dev/null, basically doesn't appear.

**But what about the actual if-statement? What's responsible for it becoming true or false?**

To further elaborate, here's an example with actual commands:

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep terminator > /dev/null
then
echo "Success"
else
echo "Fail"
fi
```

I do know that the functionality behaves in the way that if any output occurs (Process is running) in that execution the condition is True, if nothing occurs (Process not running), the condition is False.

**But I don't understand why or how it's coming to that conclusion? Is the shell if statement always expecting a string output as True?**

I've also just discovered `pgrep` but the question would also remain if the statement were

```
if pgreg -f terminator > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are testing  the exit status of grep itself, which will return false (1) if there was no match and true (0) if there was one

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep terminator > /dev/null
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi
```

you could put a "-q" instead of redirection to /dev/null

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -q terminator 
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi
```

I would execute my commad and test the $?

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep terminator
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'it is ok'
else
    echo 'is is ko'
fi
```

If you do:

```
if linux-command-1 | linux-command-2 | linux-command-3 > /dev/null
```

only the result of the last command matter

if everything is important put "&&" instead

```
if  ps -ae | grep  'bash' | grep  'pty0' && ls . >/dev/null; then     
  echo "bash is in the house" 
fi
```

that will fail because there is no not_exist

```
if  ps -ae | grep  'bash' | grep  'pty0' && ls not_exist >/dev/null; then     
  echo "bash is in the house" 
fi
```

Comment: Which grep, the first or the second?

Comment: The second, the first will be ignored, so far I can tell. So it is actually the exit code I'm testing for?

Comment: Is that independent of the command? So, will `if command` always test for the exit code of the last command?

Comment: Also, I prefer the redirection to `/dev/null` actually, because it's a little more self-explanatory to the eye. With your proposition I would need to know that the `-q` runs `grep` in silent mode, or others would need to look it up if they look at it. I'm a python guy, so readable code is preferred to me.

Comment: for me the condition  with the "-q" is on your last grep. But you are agree that if the first fails the second will too

Comment: The first one can't really fail because you grep for the process grep and invert the output, meaning all processes other than grep. And grab was called in the moment it was also searching for itself, so... can't really wrap my head around how it could fail, or at least it's irrelevant to the question. Could you clarify your answer, that the if-statement actually checks for the exit code of the executed commands, irrelevant of the command?

Comment: Yes HackXit you are right. I was talking for general case. for example if it was not for the grep process. But thank you to point it out.